# Leave Histograms (Leave Pattern) generation in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

```
 In the Data shown,we need to do a continuous pattern check of Leaves,
```

for eg:

```
CASE
WHEN count("Leaves") BETWEEN 1 AND 2 THEN '1-2'
WHEN count("Leaves") BETWEEN 3 AND 5 THEN '3-5'
WHEN count("Leaves") >5 THEN '>5'
ELSE 'Above 5' END AS "Leave Occurence",
```

On Jan 1st and 2nd employee has taken 2 leaves togather which belongs to 
'1-2'Bucket,
similarly  8,9,10,11th JAN it is contineous for 4 Days hence in '3-4'Bucket
and contineously more than 5 Leaves belongs to [<5]Bucket

Now we need the count of each Bucket for Month wise.
Here 1-2Bucket is 2
     3-4Bucket is 1
     <5 Bucket is also 1

We used this code ,but it gives the SUM,But not checking the contineous pattern

```
Year Month Leaves
2011 1-Jan 1
     2-Jan 1
     3-Jan 0
     4-Jan 0
     5-Jan 0
     6-Jan 0
     7-Jan 0
     8-Jan 1
     9-Jan 1
    10-Jan 1
    11-Jan 1
    12-Jan 0
    13-Jan 0
    14-Jan 0
    15-Jan 1
    16-Jan 1
    17-Jan 1
    18-Jan 1
    19-Jan 1
    20-Jan 1
    21-Jan 0
    22-Jan 0
    23-Jan 1
    24-Jan 1
```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Removed the [tag:sqlalchemy] tag since this would not seem to be related to said Python library.

Answer (score 0):

You can identify each group of leaves by counting the number of non-leaves before it.  Then you have aggregation:

```
select min(date), max(date), count(*) as numdays
from (select t.*,
             (select count(*)
              from t t2
              where t2.date <= t.date and t2.leave = 0
             ) as grp
      from t
      where t.leave = 1
     ) t
group by grp;
```

You can then format the results however you like.  This gives you one row per continuous "leave" period.